# Building for the Android errors Unity3D

Tags: android, unity

EDIT:

After doing some research on my own I found that by deleting the debug.keystore file everything fixed itself.

So currently I'm exporting my game strictly for testing to the Android.

However, when I attempt to build for the Android, I get these errors:

> Using keystore: C:\Users\Tim Williams.android\debug.keystore THIS TOOL IS >DEPRECATED. See --help for more information.
>
> Debug Certificate expired on 4/14/12 11:18 AM
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object) PostProcessAndroidPlayer:BuildApk(String, >Boolean) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/b0bcff80449a48aa/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostProcessAndroidPlayer.cs:1014) PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess(BuildTarget, String, String, String, String, String, String, BuildOptions) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/b0bcff80449a48aa/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostProcessAndroidPlayer.cs:444) UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

And

> Error building Player: UnityException: APK Builder Failed! Failed to build APK >package. See the Console for details.

Does anyone have any ideas what these errors are, and how I could fix them? This is my first time building for any mobile device, so I'm a bit confused (Also, I do have the Android SDK.)

Thanks,

Tim.

Comment: Congratulations, you've been developing for Android for 1 year. ;) Please reference the insanely popular post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194808/debug-certificate-expired-error-in-eclipse-android-plugins

Comment: Since this problem has been solved I'm going to go ahead and close this question since otherwise it'll just get bumped.